# Display data from database to forms in Symfony2

Tags: forms, doctrine-orm, symfony

In this project I'm building, I have many forms to add data to the database that the site uses. Obviously, if a user add's data they must be able to edit this data (or delete it).

I've looked through the book and it talks at length about using a form to add data. However, it doesn't seem to mention how forms can be used to edit data.

How can this be achieved?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want, it's quite easy to write your edit action without doctrine, you should do something like this:

```
public function editAction( $id ) {
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$repository = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:YourEntity');
$element = $repository->find( $id );
if ( false !== is_null( $element ) ) {
    throw $this->createNotFoundException( 'Couldn\'t find element ' . $id . '!');
}
$form = $this->createForm( new YourFormType(), $element );
$request = $this->getRequest();
if ( $request->getMethod() == 'POST' ) {
    $form->bindRequest( $request );
    if ( $form->isValid() ) {
        $em->persist( $element );
        $em->flush();
        $this->get( 'session' )->setFlash( 'system-message', 'Element Updated!' );
        return $this->redirect( $this->generateUrl( 'Your_route' ) );
    }
}
return $this->render('YourBundle:YourView:your_template.html.twig', array( 'element' => $element, 'form' => $form->createView() ) );}
```

The only different thing of the *edit* action with the *new* action is that, instead of creating a new "element" instance, you get it from the entity manager, you could even set any arbitrary values to your element before attaching it to the form.

I hope it helps!

Comment: That has helped a lot. However, it doesn't edit the record. It instead retrieves the record, then adds it as a new record after I submit it. What is causing that?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `generate:doctrine:crud` task to generate code for editing/updating users. You'll see that the newAction and the editAction are very similar.

Comment: What will this do exactly? I have written code that persists data to the database which works fine. Will this command overwrite this code?

Comment: Good question... I don't know. Use version control to avoid surprises.

Comment: Why does this command feel like the big red button your not supposed to press. I will get back to you when I try it.

Comment: Do not live in fear. Use version control. A DCVS like git will perfectly do the job.